# Paypal SDK and Android

Tags: android, paypal, android-studio

I'm trying to implement Paypal Payment in my app. I get the example from here : 
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK.
When I launch the app with eclipse everything is good.
But when I try to add the activity, the xml file, and the manifest in my own app in Android Studio (V 0.6.0), an error appears since yesterday.
I can't call my method onBuyPressed with the line android:onClick="onBuyPressed" in my button.
I have this error :

```
06-09 20:57:45.851  10161-10161/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onBuyPressed(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'buyItBtn'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3724)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4274)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17357)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onBuyPressed [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3717)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4274)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17357)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

You can see my activity here :

```
package net.sparkeek.test.cubydroid.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalAuthorization;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalItem;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPaymentDetails;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.math.BigDecimal;


public class PaypalActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "paymentExample";
    /**
     * - Set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION to move real money.
     *
     * - Set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX to use your test credentials
     * from https://developer.paypal.com
     *
     * - Set to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK to kick the tires
     * without communicating to PayPal's servers.
     */
    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;

    // note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox environments.
    private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "credential from developer.paypal.com";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT = 2;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
            .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
                    // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
            .merchantName("Hipster Store")
            .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
            .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_paypal);
        /*Button btnSouscription = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSouscription);
        btnSouscription.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBuyPressed(v);
            }
        });*/

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        startService(intent);
    }


    public void onBuyPressed(View v) {
        /*
         * PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE will cause the payment to complete immediately.
         * Change PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE to PAYMENT_INTENT_AUTHORIZE to only authorize payment and
         * capture funds later.
         *
         * Also, to include additional payment details and an item list, see getStuffToBuy() below.
         */
        PayPalPayment thingToBuy = getThingToBuy(PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(PaypalActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
    }

    private PayPalPayment getThingToBuy(String paymentIntent) {
        return new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("1.75"), "USD", "hipster jeans",
                paymentIntent);
    }

    /*
     * This method shows use of optional payment details and item list.
     */
    private PayPalPayment getStuffToBuy(String paymentIntent) {
        PayPalItem[] items =
                {
                        new PayPalItem("old jeans with holes", 2, new BigDecimal("87.50"), "USD",
                                "sku-12345678"),
                        new PayPalItem("free rainbow patch", 1, new BigDecimal("0.00"),
                                "USD", "sku-zero-price"),
                        new PayPalItem("long sleeve plaid shirt (no mustache included)", 6, new BigDecimal("37.99"),
                                "USD", "sku-33333")
                };
        BigDecimal subtotal = PayPalItem.getItemTotal(items);
        BigDecimal shipping = new BigDecimal("7.21");
        BigDecimal tax = new BigDecimal("4.67");
        PayPalPaymentDetails paymentDetails = new PayPalPaymentDetails(shipping, subtotal, tax);
        BigDecimal amount = subtotal.add(shipping).add(tax);
        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(amount, "USD", "hipster jeans", paymentIntent);
        return payment.items(items).paymentDetails(paymentDetails);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PaymentConfirmation confirm =
                        data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirm != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i(TAG, confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                        Log.i(TAG, confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString(4));
                        /**
                         *  TODO: send 'confirm' (and possibly confirm.getPayment() to your server for verification
                         * or consent completion.
                         * See https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                         * for more details.
                         *
                         * For sample mobile backend interactions, see
                         * https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend
                         */
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "PaymentConfirmation info received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i(
                        TAG,
                        "An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PayPalAuthorization auth =
                        data.getParcelableExtra(PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
                if (auth != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", auth.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                        String authorization_code = auth.getAuthorizationCode();
                        Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", authorization_code);

                        sendAuthorizationToServer(auth);
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Future Payment code received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("FuturePaymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i(
                        "FuturePaymentExample",
                        "Probably the attempt to previously start the PayPalService had an invalid PayPalConfiguration. Please see the docs.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendAuthorizationToServer(PayPalAuthorization authorization) {

        /**
         * TODO: Send the authorization response to your server, where it can
         * exchange the authorization code for OAuth access and refresh tokens.
         *
         * Your server must then store these tokens, so that your server code
         * can execute payments for this user in the future.
         *
         * A more complete example that includes the required app-server to
         * PayPal-server integration is available from
         * https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend
         */

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Stop service when done
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

My XML file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="net.sparkeek.test.cubydroid.app.PaypalActivity" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buyItBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:onClick="onBuyPressed"
            android:text="Buy a Thing" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.sparkeek.test.cubydroid.app" >

    <!-- for most things, including card.io & paypal -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- for card.io card scanning -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_cuby"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".PaypalActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_paypal" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentConsentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentInfoActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="io.card.payment.CardIOActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you provide the contents of your build.gradle file, and the relevant file system structure?  You are using Gradle within Android Studio, right?  Compiling or including the library more than once would cause that error, but I would need more information to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is private but getMethod() only returns public method.

You need to use getDeclaredMethod().

Comment: I think no, because I have exactly the same code in eclipse, and it works.